# In what case SQL will use an Index of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

During an interview I was asked a weird question. I could not find the correct answer for it, so posting the question below:

I have an index on a column Stud_Name. I am searching for name using a wild card. My query is

a) select *  from Stud_Details where Stud_Name like 'A%'

b) select * from Stud_Details where Stud_Name like '%A'.

c) select * from Stud_Details where Stud_Name not like 'A%'

In which case would the SQL server use the Index, that I have created on Stud_Name?

PS: If this question seems idiotic don't get mad on me, get mad on the interviewer who asked this to me.
Also I don't have any info regarding how the index was created. This info above is all I have.

Comment: http://duhallowgreygeek.com/like-initial-wildcard-sql-smell/   Can't use index with leading wildcard.  I *think* the `not like` can use an index.

Comment: for all cases the index can be used

Answer (score 3):

**In what cases *can* SQL Server use an Index on Stud_Name?**

- Option (a) is the only one that can be used in an index **seek**. `like 'A%'` can get converted to a range seek on `>= A` and `<B`
- Option (b) can't use an index seek as the leading wildcard prevents this. It could still scan an index though.
- Option (c) could in theory be converted to two range seeks (`< 'A' OR >= 'B'` but I've just checked and SQL Server does not do that (even in cases where this would eliminate 100% of the table and with a `FORCESEEK` hint). Again it can scan an index though.

**In what cases *will* SQL Server use an Index on Stud_Name?**

This depends on cardinality estimates and whether the index is covering or not and the relative width of the index rows vs the base table rows.

Assuming the index is not covering then any rows found that match the `WHERE` clause will need lookups to retrieve the column values. The greater the number of estimated lookups the less likely the non covering index is to be used.

For b+c the choice is index scan + lookups vs table scan with no lookups. The favourability of doing an index scan will be higher if the index is much narrower than the table. If they are similar sizes there is not much IO benefit from reading the index rather than the table in the first place.

Comment: @lptr - yes. as it comes down to expected number of lookups for the `select * `. In the best case it scans the narrow index, finds no matching rows and does not need to do any lookups at all

Comment: It is also not doing options C - options C likely is not going to make the index statistically relevant. You would have to eliminate a significant part of the table for it to make sense.

Comment: @TomTom - SQL Server *does* do the equivalent for `where Stud_Name <> 'A'` even though that just eliminates one single value. not a whole range of values. If the index is covering it converts the `<>` to a `< 'A'` and `> 'A'` and has a seek with those two seek predicates

Comment: But it is statistics driven. WHic his what I say. If you hav a million rows you really may not eliminate a lot - so you may end up with the cost base optimizer saying "damn, not worth it".

Comment: (edit comment)...option b could use an index scan. Wouldn't it be more expensive to scan the whole table when all names are NOT ending in A?

Comment: I don't believe SQL Server has any transformation rule to convert `not like 'A%'` to `< 'A' OR >= 'B'` as it couldn't generate a plan with `FORCESEEK` so even if you have a million rows all of which begin with A it isn't going to do it and the manual rewrite might be worth considering